# Error during executing the React native project on Android emulator on Mac M1

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I can successfully sync my project with the android studio but I am running the project then I am getting an Error:

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'booleancom.swmansion.ranimated.layoutReanimation.NativeMethidsHolder.isLayoutAnimationEnabled()' on a null object

[Please see the attached image for the complete error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwBp2.png)